# Is running Kestrel on Linux without a reverse proxy recommended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, nginx, kestrel-http-server

I have seen a lot of articles say that it is not advised to expose Kestrel directly to the internet. It is better to use it behind a reverse proxy like Nginx. However, almost all of these sites are 4+ years old and no  MSDN references I came across mention this.

Is running Kestrel behind a proxy on Linux still recommended?

Comment: Microsoft has a documentation page to help you decide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Nowadays with cloud providers you would probably use load balancer (e.g. AWS ELB) to expose any service to internet anyway in which case Nginx is not needed. However Nginx might still be useful for example to expose several internal services on the same URL (using different sub-paths via `location`) or on the same base URL using `server_name`. It is especially easy to add Nginx when services are running as Docker containers (via common `docker-compose.yml`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes.

Long answer:
Your question is not bounded to Kestrel and Nginx, but it's the topic of web server (WS) and reverse proxy (RP). Putting a WS behind a RP has multiple benefits, see [here](https://avinetworks.com/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/#:%7E:text=A%20reverse%20proxy%20server%20can,web%20server%20will%20become%20overloaded.)

But essentially:

1. Load balancing: you can have multiple instances of WS running, and the RP will load balance requests to these WS. So WS will not be flooded with requests on burst. And if a WS crashes, there will be other instances running, so no downtime.
2. Caching static content: a RP caches and responds css/image/js/html to request to reduce workload of a WS. So WS can focus on other cpu intensive tasks for instance.
3. Protection from DDoS, standard RP has built-in mechanism to prevent DDoS attacks.
4. SSL https encrypts all request content. So no middleman sniffing your network package.

With all these benefits, there is no reason not to use reverse proxy. Regardless of Linux, Windows, ASP.NET, PHP, Nginx, IIS, Apache,...